# Getting an AppEngine entity by serialized key

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, app-engine-ndb

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get) for the `Model` class, I can use the `.get()` class function to retrieve one or more entities from the AppEngine datastore by their keys (as `Key` or `string`). I've got a model `Entry`:

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
  def to_dict(self):
    ret = ndb.Model.to_dict(self)
    ret['key'] = self.key.urlsafe()
    return ret

class Entry(Model):
  text = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  ...
```

You'll notice I automatically add the entity's key to the `.to_dict()` result for my common model subclass so that when they're serialized to JSON for the client, then sent back to the server by a client AJAX call, I can find the corresponding entities in the datastore (pretty simple, right?). The problem is, I'm now trying to fetch those entities in Python with serialized keys from the client via:

```
entries = Entry.get(entryKeys)
```

... but I'm instead receiving the following error:

```
type object 'Entry' has no attribute 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/cbehar/dev/dada/handlers.py", line 126, in post
    entries = Entry.get(entryKeys)
AttributeError: type object 'Entry' has no attribute 'get'
```

Is the documentation out of date or am I just doing something stupid?

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward. I could just use `db.get()` instead, but `Model.get()` is supposed to have additional type-checking and, at this point, I really just want to know what the hell I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was actually looking at the documentation for the old DB datastore, not the new NDB datastore.

According to [this handy doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic),

```
google.appengine.ext.db            | ndb.model
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
MyModel.get_by_key_name('my_key')  | MyModel.get_by_id('my_key')
MyModel.get_by_id(42)              | MyModel.get_by_id(42)
db.get(key)                        | key.get()
MyModel.get(key)                   | key.get()
db.get(model_instance)             | model_instance.key.get()
db.get(list_of_keys)               | ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)
db.get(list_of_instances)          | ndb.get_multi([x.key for x in
                                   |                list_of_instances])
MyModel.get_or_insert('my_key',    | MyModel.get_or_insert('my_key',  
  parent=model_instance,           |   parent=model_instance.key,
  foo='bar')                       |   foo='bar')
```

So it looks like the answer is something like:

```
ndb.get_multi(ndb.Key(entryKey) for entryKey in entryKeys)
```

Answer (score -1):

To retreive an entity via a keyID you need to call your object with this methode:

```
ObjectName.get_by_id(int(your key)))
```

This is a complet sample about that:

```
class KeyValueStore(ndb.Model):
    key_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True);
    value = ndb.JsonProperty(required=True)
    last_record = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

    def getDict(self):
        master = self.to_dict()
        master["key"] = self.key.id()
        return master

    @classmethod
    def getByKey(cls, key=None):
        if key != "" and key != None:
            record = KeyValueStore.get_by_id(int(key))
            if record:
                json = record[0].value
                return json
            else:
                return {}
        else:
            return {}
```